# javascript character count for a textarea... is not working, but it works for <input type="text">'s

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have code that is intended to show the user the number of remaining characters available
 in text boxes and text areas.  Only the code works flawlessly for `<input type="text">`'s and doesn't work at all for `<textarea>`'s.

I'm not sure why...  My code is below

My js--

```
 function toCount(entrance,exit,text,characters) {  
  var entranceObj=getObject(entrance);  
  var exitObj=getObject(exit);  
  var length=characters - entranceObj.value.length;  
  if(length <= 0) {  
    length=0;  
    text='<span class="disable"> '+text+' </span>';  
    entranceObj.value=entranceObj.value.substr(0,characters);  
  }  
  exitObj.innerHTML = text.replace("{CHAR}",length);  
}
```

My html

```
<textarea style="overflow-x: hidden;" value="<%=strVariable %>" type="text" id="gBann"       
name="MyName" maxlength="1000" size="1000" rows="8" cols="40"   
onKeyUp="toCount('gBann','uBann','{CHAR} characters remaining',1000);" >  
</textarea>  
<span id="uBann" class="minitext">1000 characters remaining</span>
```

Comment: I dont see any problem with your code. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `document.getElementById` instead of getObject.

So the following works:

```
function toCount(entrance,exit,text,characters) {  
    var entranceObj=document.getElementById(entrance);  
    var exitObj=document.getElementById(exit);  
    var length=characters - entranceObj.value.length;  
    if(length <= 0) {  
    length=0;  
    text='<span class="disable"> '+text+' <\/span>';  
    entranceObj.value=entranceObj.value.substr(0,characters);  
    }  
    exitObj.innerHTML = text.replace("{CHAR}",length);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but a `textarea` doesn't work like an `input[type=text]` in the sense that you have to echo the value *inside the element* like this:

```
<textarea>test</textarea>
```

Instead of this:

```
<textarea value="test"></textarea>
```

However, the `value` attribute of a textarea DOM element should be accessible in the same way, as can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/bwGKk/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this javascript:

```
function Counter(txtfield, limit) { 

            if (txtfield.value.length > maxlimit)
                txtfield.value = txtfield.value.substring(0, maxlimit);

            // else, update 'characters left' counter
            else {                
                document.getElementById('myCounter').innerHTML = maxlimit - txtfield.value.length
            }        
        }
```

Here "myCounter" is a span id as in 500
and "txtfield" is the textarea ID.

My ASP code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" onKeyUp="javascript:textCounter(this,<%=Count%>);" onKeyDown="javascript:textCounter(this,<%=Count%>);"></asp:TextBox>
```